# How to check passed date as input is in UTC timezone or not?

Tags: java

How can I restrict client to pass only UTC timezone date? I am expecting client should pass date in this format only: yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ e.g. 20130710T00:41:19.004+0000 .

If client passed date with offset like 20130710T00:41:19.004+0500, I should not accept this date.

Here is our requirement: 
Client will call our webservice methods, client will always convert date to UTC timezone i.e. 20130710T00:41:19.004+0000  and pass to our webservice method. but anyway we should have logic in our side if any case client has passed date like 20130710T00:41:19.004+0500, we should not process there request.

I tried SimpleDateFormat(yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ) and tried to parse the Date (20130710T00:41:19.004+0500), it is not throwing any exception. I am expecting it should not parse the date.

Is there any way or api to check input date is in above format(Only in UTC) or not?

Comment: You will need to provide a bit more detail here.  (1) how is the data "passed"? (2) why do you want to require this format? (3) `yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ` and `yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss.SSS±zzzz` are different do you care?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat.  Create one with your expected format, if it throws an exception, you have been given a date in the wrong format.

Comment: But why you need such behavior? If the user is giving you the offset, then he is in fact giving you the UTC time because you can simply find out the corresponding UTC time for the time given by user.  Just bear in mind, Date in Java do not contain any timezone information.  That's always UTC.  Therefore, given a proper date-time string with timezone offset, the result date after you parse by SimpleDateFormat is a Date object "in UTC".

Answer (score 1):

If you want your input string to use this format (`yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ`), assuming the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) formatting and only allow inputs in the UTC timezone, simply check that the string ends with `00`, `+0000` or `-0000` before passing it to the parser.

Comment: thanks for your input. This will be our last option. I am looking something like request interceptor validator (un/marsheller) should get fail.

Comment: It sounds like you're not really after the actual validation operation (as your question suggests), but rather querying more generally about validating your web service input. Hard to answer without knowing which framework you're using. In addition, as @AdrianShum said, there's little point in banning time inputs with a time zone that's not UTC. (The biggest problems with date/time data is when the time zones are missing altogether and you have to guess. Having a non-UTC time zone is always easy to convert to UTC in your application.)